# Loading stylesheets and scripts dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I want to dynamically load stylesheets and scripts that are in a variable. This is my current code.

```
<span ng-init="stylesheets = []"></span>
<span ng-init="scripts = []"></span>

<span ng-repeat="script in scripts">
  <script src="{{script}}"></script>
</span>

<span ng-repeat="stylesheet in stylesheets">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{stylesheet}}"/>
</span>
```

My code is already working except that initially it loads the literals `{{script}}` and `{{stylesheet}}` which is adding up to the request time to the server.

[image]

I would like to avoid this.

Comment: are you looking for `ng-src` and `ng-href`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: It worked! But why does angular not working when I explicitly write `<script ng-src="auth-service.module.js"></script>`

Comment: Oh, it only works when the value have {{}} markup. Solved.

Comment: most likely that approach won't work in some IE.